# Convert special string by regular expression with PHP

Tags: php, regex

How can I convert `X@[Y](type:NUM)Z` to `<a href="/NUM">Y</a>` by **RegEx** with php as: `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `NUM` are changeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `$string = "X@[Y](type:NUM)"`

```
preg_match("/.*@\[(.*)\]\(type:(.*)\)/",$string,$matches);
```

Y : $matches[1] 
NUM : $matches[2]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after

```
/(.)@\[(.)\](.+type:)(.+)(.)/
```

[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/gRhJvM/1)

1st Capturing Group (.)
. matches any character
@ matches the character @ literally
[ matches the character [ literally

2nd Capturing Group (.)
. matches any character
] matches the character ] literally

3rd Capturing Group (.+type:)
.+
 matches any character

4th Capturing Group (.+)
.+
 matches any character

5th Capturing Group (.)
. matches any character